# Compare a byte[] or a Base64String to a T-SQL timestamp

Tags: c#, t-sql, timestamp, base64

How to compare something like this: `AAAAAA1iUFw=` (a Base64String converted from a Byte Array) to something like this `0x000000000BFF1E5A` (T-SQL)?

I wanna find the tablerow by this base64String like:

```
select * from table1 where timestampCol = 'AAAAAA1iUFw='
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it? How should they match?

Comment: because I got the timestamp by debugging and want to find/compare it with the database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting value to varbinay will help:

```
-- Convert Base64 value to varbinary 
select cast ('AAAAAA1iUFw=' as varbinary(20))
```